# Serialize a std::queue

Tags: c++, serialization, queue

I would like to serialize a `std::queue<long long int>` that contains several elements (approximately a couple of millions), so that I can recover it on the following execution of the program. Is there an easy way to do so without using `boost` or other external libraries?
An obvious alternative would be that of writing the integers to a file and then reading them and putting them in a queue, but I feel like this would be a less efficient approach.

Comment: *"I feel like"* and *"efficient"* in the same sentence screams premature optimization. A priori (that is, until you can prove otherwise), just writing the integers is just fine. Should be IO bound anyways.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Now I feel like you may be right and I should try doing it by just writing the integers. Then if I am not satisfied, I may try to find alternative solutions... :)

Comment: You could create an array, copy the integers from the queue into the array, then block write (in binary) the array.  Since your operation is I/O bound, this will enable you to keep the output flowing, reducing the output time.  Memory copying (from queue to array) is negligible compared to the output time.